# Cors issue API not on same server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm using Web API 2. in my WebApiConfig, I have this.

```
   private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var origin = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["origin"];
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(

            origins: "*",
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

Register Method

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandler());
    }
```

From my understanding shouldn't that all I need to for this to work? It's worked on my dev computer when they are hosted together. But now one is on a web server and the API is on a different web server.

I'm getting - **Origin ...  not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.**

I have it set to allow all Origin. I've tried adding it in the web config , and other methods posted around Stack overflow. I don't understand why its being denied?

Front end is Angular, using Ngresource for requests.

If I use the Network Tab in chrome dev tools, the Response to the request is 200 OK, and nothing else happens after that. Been searching all day for solutions, nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Thank you.

Comment: find more details here...
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding shouldn't that all I need to for this to work?

Nope. You should decorate the Web API controllers/actions that you would like to be calling cross domain with the `[EnableCors]` attribute:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

Here's a [`good read`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on this topic.

Comment: I have it enabled in the WebAiiConfig file, in the Register method. This should enable it globally. I've read in quite a few places that its how u enable Cors globally. I edited my original post to show it.

Comment: Yes, I see your post. Now try adding the attribute as shown in my answer to your controller. Don't trust everything you read :-)

Comment: Can just do [EnableCors] It needs parameters

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you are right. You need to specify the parameters. I have updated my answer with an example taken from the documentation.

Comment: Tried this, 
[EnableCors(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*")] (astrisks to allow all)
get the same error :(

Comment: I hope you kept the `config.EnableCors` declaration in your global, did you?

Comment: Yes, I havent changed anything else in the WebApiConfig.

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. This has always worked for me perfectly fine. I would recommend you following the simple tutorial outlined in the documentation: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api Maybe you are missing some point. Once you have a simple example working you will be able to build on top of it.